# How to get time in milliseconds in Android Shell?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a shell script to run on Android. I need to measure time at more precision than seconds - milliseconds or nanoseconds. How can I do it in Android Shell?

The `date +%N` does not give time in nanoseconds - it just gives `N` as output. I cannot find any other command/way to do it.

In Android API we can get it easily, so there must be a way to do it through shell too.

Comment: Could you try `date +%s%N` ?

Comment: as I said, using %N only gives N. so date +%s%N gives 2234232N (the number is some random time in seconds)

Comment: @shoerat - I want more precision than seconds. milliseconds or micro or nano. your method only gives seconds

Comment: `date +%s` * 1000? :)

Comment: @shoerat - lol. but not of any use :)

Answer (score 0):

First install busybox for android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en

Then you can do:
adb shell "busybox date +%s"

to get the time in seconds and:
adb shell "busybox date +%N"

to get the nano seconds.

Comment: Root just to get the date?  That's silly.  If you are installing a native executable to do this, it hardly needs to be root - it's a few lines of C code.

Comment: `+%N` doesn't work for me. It only echos text `%N`.